# Why are autoregressive models neither directed or undirected, as described in the NADE paper?

Tags: neural-networks, graphical-model, generative-models

In the paper [Neural Autoregressive Distribution Estimation (Uria et al., 2016)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume17/16-272/16-272.pdf), NADE (and other autoregressive models) seem to be described as neither directed or undirected models:

> We’ve described the Neural Autoregressive Distribution Estimator, a
> tractable, flexible and competitive alternative to directed and
> undirected graphical models for unsupervised distribution estimation
>
> ...
>
> NADE thus substantially differs from this literature focusing on
> directed and undirected models, benefiting from a few properties that
> these approaches lack. Mainly, NADE does not rely on latent stochastic
> hidden units, making it possible to tractably compute its associated
> data likelihood for some given ordering. This in turn makes it
> possible to efficiently produce exact samples from the model (unlike
> in undirected models) and get an unbiased gradient for maximum
> likelihood training (unlike in directed graphical models).

[These slides by Russ Salakhutdinov](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ersalakhu/Lecture1.pdf) seem to agree that autoregressive models (subset of fully observed) are separate from "undirected DGMs" and "directed DGMs":

[image: Salakhutdinov talk roadmap]

How is this possible? Is it because autoregressive models lack a hierarchy?

However, my intuition is that they are directed, as the [Flow-GAN blogpost by Aditya Grover and Manik Dhar](https://ermongroup.github.io/blog/flow-gan/) suggests.

Similarly, according to a tutorial on generative models by Shakir Mohamed and Danilo Rezende from DeepMind at UAI 2017 ([video recording](https://youtu.be/JrO5fSskISY?t=1319) and [slides](https://www.shakirm.com/slides/DeepGenModelsTutorial.pdf)), autoregressive models such as NADE and PixelCNN are classified as directed models:

[image: Spectrum of fully-observed models]

---

Answer (score 0):

I agree the terminology is misleading -- perhaps a more precise naming would be (un)directed *latent variable* generative models.

So a "directed latent variable generative model" is any model in the form $P(x) = \int P(x|h)P(h) dh$, where $h$ is the latent variable. This includes VAEs, GANs, and flows. The slide you shows probably just splits GANs off into a separate category because it's such a large topic.

But in the strict sense yes, an autoregressive model is indeed a directed graphical model.